# Start JavaFX Spring project with 'mvn spring-boot:run'

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, javafx, spring-boot-maven-plugin

How can I start a spring-boot project in place with maven that extends `javafx.application.Application` that contains no main method?  Every time I try to start it with maven the error below gets shown.

Error message:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project chatClient: An exception occurred while running. The specified mainClass doesn't contain a main method with appropriate signature.: XX.XXX.ChatClient.main([Ljava.lang.String;) -> [Help 1]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>XX.XXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>chatClient</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <start-class>XX.XXX.ChatClient</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

ChatClient.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ChatClient extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent root;

    @Override
    public void init() throws IOException {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(ChatClient.class);

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/root.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        root = fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Chat client");
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }
}
```

root.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<BorderPane></BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

with:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
```

There is no need to specify mainClass.

[Here](https://wimdeblauwe.wordpress.com/2017/09/18/using-spring-boot-with-javafx/) you have a full example.

**UPDATE**

Now I notice you do not have a main method. Add this code to `ChatClient` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(ChatClient.class, args);
}
```

Comment: If I do the proposed changes it can't find the main class. `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project chatClient: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass'property -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @XXLPitu How do you run it? With `mvn spring-boot:run`?

Comment: Yes, I run `mvn spring-boot:run` where the pom is located.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seemed to have been the trick. I've assumed I don't need it since IntelliJ can start it with no main method.